# BLSTM encoder in seq2seq model Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I want to create a bidirectional RNN Encoder in 
embedding_attention_seq2seq 
in 
        seq2seq_model.py :
here is the code blew

```
def embedding_attention_seq2seq(encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs, cell,
  num_encoder_symbols, num_decoder_symbols,
  num_heads=1, output_projection=None,
  feed_previous=False, dtype=dtypes.float32,
  scope=None, initial_state_attention=False):

  with variable_scope.variable_scope(scope or"embedding_attention_seq2seq"):
  # Encoder.
  encoder_cell = rnn_cell.EmbeddingWrapper(cell, num_encoder_symbols)
  encoder_outputs, encoder_state = rnn.rnn(
  encoder_cell, encoder_inputs, dtype=dtype)

 # First calculate a concatenation of encoder outputs to put attention on.
  top_states = [array_ops.reshape(e, [-1, 1, cell.output_size])
  for e in encoder_outputs]
  attention_states = array_ops.concat(1, top_states)
  ....
```

Here the code I changed.Borrowed from https://github.com/ematvey/tensorflow-seq2seq-tutorials/blob/master/2-seq2seq-advanced.ipynb

```
# Encoder.
encoder_cell = copy.deepcopy(cell)
encoder_cell = core_rnn_cell.EmbeddingWrapper(
    encoder_cell,
    embedding_classes=num_encoder_symbols,
    embedding_size=embedding_size)
(encoder_outputs,          
encoder_fw_final_state,
encoder_bw_final_state)=rnn.bidirectional_rnn(
    cell_fw=encoder_cell,
    cell_bw=encoder_cell,
    encoder_inputs, 
    dtype=dtype)
encoder_final_state_c = tf.concat(
(encoder_fw_final_state.c, encoder_bw_final_state.c), 1)

encoder_final_state_h = tf.concat(
(encoder_fw_final_state.h, encoder_bw_final_state.h), 1)

encoder_state = LSTMStateTuple(
c=encoder_final_state_c,
h=encoder_final_state_h)
```

list of errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "translate.py", line 301, in <module>
tf.app.run()
File "/home/tensorflow/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
File "translate.py", line 297, in main
train()
File "translate.py", line 156, in train
model = create_model(sess, False)
File "translate.py", line 134, in create_model
dtype=dtype)
File "/home/tensorflow/Downloads/NMT-jp-ch-master/seq2seq_model.py", line 185, in __init__
softmax_loss_function=softmax_loss_function)
File "/home/tensorflow/Downloads/NMT-jp-ch-master/seq2seq.py", line 628, in model_with_buckets
decoder_inputs[:bucket[1]])
File "/home/tensorflow/Downloads/NMT-jp-ch-master/seq2seq_model.py", line 184, in <lambda>
lambda x, y: seq2seq_f(x, y, False),
File "/home/tensorflow/Downloads/NMT-jp-ch-master/seq2seq_model.py", line 148, in seq2seq_f
dtype=dtype)
File "/home/tensorflow/Downloads/NMT-jp-ch-master/seq2seq.py", line 432, in embedding_attention_seq2seq
inputs=encoder_inputs
File "/home/tensorflow/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 652, in bidirectional_dynamic_rnn
time_major=time_major, scope=fw_scope)
File "/home/tensorflow/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 789, in dynamic_rnn
for input_ in flat_input)
File "/home/tensorflow/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 789, in <genexpr>
for input_ in flat_input)
File "/home/tensorflow/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1280, in transpose
ret = gen_array_ops.transpose(a, perm, name=name)
File "/home/tensorflow/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 3656, in transpose
result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Transpose", x=x, perm=perm, name=name)
File "/home/tensorflow/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)
File "/home/tensorflow/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2242, in create_op
set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
File "/home/tensorflow/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1617, in set_shapes_for_outputs
shapes = shape_func(op)
File "/home/tensorflow/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1568, in call_with_requiring
return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
File "/home/tensorflow/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 610, in call_cpp_shape_fn
debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
File "/home/tensorflow/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 675, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
raise ValueError(err.message)
ValueError: Dimension must be 1 but is 3 for 'model_with_buckets/embedding_attention_seq2seq/BiRNN/FW/transpose' (op: 'Transpose') with input shapes: [?], [3].
```

I use py3.4 and tf-v0.12

How to create the proper bidirectional RNN Encoder with the https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/rnn.py in seq2seq model ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by

top_states = [array_ops.reshape(e, [-1, 1, cell.output_size*2])

Yes，reshape should *2 .